# How to monitor IIS install with 50 sites

Tags: iis, monitoring

I have a web server running IIS 6.0 -- and at least 50 web sites, probably half running SSL

Is there a way to tell in real time what sites are demanding the most system resources, the most traffic, and whatever else should be monitored on a server-wide basis.

No, I don't want to parse the IIS logs.   I'm looking for some way to monitor IIS in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Technet article to MS Performance monitor [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3ffd9ede-2bc8-4bdc-871e-9d937f25d6c9.mspx?mfr=true)